# Why aren't the V-Bucks I bought on PlayStation showing on Fortnite?

Tags: ps4, psn, fortnite-battle-royale

I have a PS4, bought a 10$ PlayStation card, entered the code in PlayStation wallet, it showed I have a balance of 10$, then I purchased 1000 v-bucks from Fortnite application for 7.99$, I paid from the PS wallet, the wallet balance became 2$ but I cant see any v-bucks in Fortnite.

My Epic Games account shows no transaction happened but my PlayStation account shows I bought a 10$ game card and used 8$ to buy v-bucks.

Please let me know how I can solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Contact epic games support. We can't exactly help you other than this, I'm pretty sure nobody here works at Epic.
Or just be paitent.